# как правильно сделать text-align:center при переносе строк и наличии иконки возле строки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Внутри div фиксированной ширины, выводится текст с иконкой слева, выравняный по центру. Когда текст переносится на следующую строку, выравнивание начинается относитеьно начала иконки. Как сделать, чтоб выравнивание начиналось относительно первой буквы, а не начала картинки?

```css
.cat_wr {
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upl3F.png) no-repeat center left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_wr">
  <span class="text">Выравнивание по центру с иконкой слева</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант использовать список, а маркер списка заменить нужной иконкой..... еще можно создать псевдокласс  `:before` задать ему контентом иконку и выводить перед текстом поигравшись со свойством `text-indent`      
Вариантов куча...

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со списком:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
}
ul {
  list-style-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upl3F.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 </li>
    <li>text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 </li>
    <li>text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Вариант с псевдоэллементом:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
p:before {
  content:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upl3F.png);
  
}
p {
  text-indent:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_wr">
<p class="text">text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1</p>
<p class="text">text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2</p>
<p class="text">text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3</p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вертикальное выравнивание картинки относительно текста не очень важно, то можно так:

```css
.cat_wr {
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upl3F.png) no-repeat 6px 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.text {

}
```

```html
<div class="cat_wr">
  <span class="text">Выравнивание по центру с иконкой слева</span>
</div>
```